# How to access deployment parameter from within EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, ejb

In a Java EE 6 Web application, I would like to access a deployment parameter (a string value) from within an `EJB`.

I know that I can define a Context Parameter in `web.xml` descriptor, and I'll be able to access it through [javax.faces.context.ExternalContext#getInitParameterMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getInitParameterMap%28%29), when I am in a `JSF` bean, and through [getServletContext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext%28%29) from within a `Servlet`, but this is not the case, indeed, because I am in an `EJB`.

So, the question is: is there any standard (and possibly clean) way to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further research, I have found out the use of `env-entry` annotation in `web.xml`.:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>myEnvEntry</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>MyEnvEntryValue</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

The `env-entry` can be accessed in various ways from an `EJB`. The simplest is the use of `@Resource` annotation (requires [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnr.html)):

```
@Resource(name="myEnvEntry")
private String myEnvEntry;
```

Links: [Configure your EJB 3 with envirnoment entries using ENC](http://www.jroller.com/agoncal/entry/configure_your_ejb_3_with)