# How to configure Glassfish to inject String in EJB3.1?

Tags: glassfish, cdi, ejb-3.1

I want to do something like that (Very basic...) :

```
  @Resource(lookup = "my/jndi/name")
  private String someString;
```

And the glassfish console isn't clear about how to configure a jndi String resource named "my/jndi/name".

Comment: If instead you want to use a parameter specifically for an application, you can see [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12450297/870122)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do something like that :

```
@Resource(lookup = "your/jndi/name")
private String someString;
```

You can use the glassfish console and add a custom resource :

[image: Custom String Value with glassfish]

Note that you must add a property with "value" as name.

And here is the corresponding glassfish-resource.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC
  "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN"
  "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <custom-resource jndi-name="your/jndi/name" res-type="java.lang.String" factory-    class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PrimitivesAndStringFactory">
        <property name="value" value="your value"></property>
    </custom-resource>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at the Configuration stuff in DeltaSpike.